# "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" on GraphQL's Mutation

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, graphql

I'm new to graphQL and node.Js and I don't know how to solve my problem.

My graphQL API works well (the query and the mutation above work in graphiQL), but when I try to use it from an application, I get the error  "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" on my mutation

here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const util = require('util');

var app = express();

const query = `
    query abc {
      test
      students {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
        fullName
        college {
          id
          name
          rating
          location
        }
      }
    }`;

const mutation = `
    mutation def {
      createStudent(collegeId: "col-101", firstName: "a", lastName: "b")
    }`;

// query
app.get('/graphql/query', function(req, res) {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({query}),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => res.render('graphql.ejs', {result: util.inspect(json, false, null), type: "Query"}));
})

// mutation
app.get('/graphql/mutation', function(req, res) {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({mutation}),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json), json => res.render('graphql.ejs', {result: util.inspect(json, false, null), type: "Mutation"}));
})



.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/graphql/query');
})

.listen(8080);
console.log("online on 8080");
```

the part about the query works fine, I only have my problem about the mutation, an idea?

Comment: Look at the response in the Network tab of DevTools. You'll probably see some HTML before the JSON.

Comment: The body of the request can contain three keys -- `query`, `variables` and `operationName`. `mutation` is not a valid key. Even though the operation is a mutation, you still use the `query` key to submit your document. That is, you need to write `JSON.stringify({query:mutation})`

Comment: @DanielRearden Thanks for the explanation, it's works !